# How to find some elements in a multi-dimensional array, with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, logic

I have a a multi-dimensional array, whose name is: `$MyArray = array();`.

This array can be used for showing the **relation** between things.

```
Array
(
    [parent] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => tom
                    [2] => bob
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => liza
                    [2] => bob
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => bob
                    [2] => john
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => pet
                    [2] => john
                )

        )

    [gender] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => tom
                    [2] => male
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => liza
                    [2] => female
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [1] => bob
                    [2] => male
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [1] => pet
                    [2] => female
                )

        )

)
```

---

Now, I want to return an array, which must be satisfied with all conditions:

- Finds in the `gender` array, what line has the `male` value. This value is called: `TempArray`.
- In what line of the `TempArray`; **and**, continue to finds what name in `Sol_1` into the `parent` array.

Then returns into a multi-dimensional array: `ResArray`, like:

```
Array
(
    [father] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => tom
                    [2] => bob
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => bob
                    [2] => john
                )

        )

        [mother] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [1] => liza
                    [2] => bob
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => pet
                    [2] => john
                )

        )

)
```

---

How to do it, with PHP?

Comment: `"Is it possible to solve this logic problem, with multi-dimensional arrays, in PHP?"`. Yes, of course it is, but you ned to show us what you have tried so far. As it stands this is a 'gimme teh codez' question.

Comment: The problem with your question is that you haven't shown what you have tried so far. However, that is only my opinion, others may not agree. You can either leave your question as is and see what the community decides, or you can have a go at writing some code and reposting if you come across a particular problem we can help with. In the meanwhile I have voted to close this as too broad. Please note that I am not saying that your question is poor or uninteresting, just that it is too broad as defined in the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: An array it's a data structure, by no means can solve anything, but you could use it to model the problem.

Comment: You might benefit from searching on [frames](http://www.amzi.com/ExpertSystemsInProlog/06frames.htm) in connection with AI and Prolog programming.  It is often useful to have essentially an array of "objects" whose attributes and states model the problem requirements.  This technique can be adapted to procedural languages from its use in declarative languages, although the coder will find themselves reinventing some parts of this "wheel".

Comment: If you want to have something similar to Prolog's inference machine you need to implement a few things: 1) you need a data-structure which makes a difference between variables and constant terms 2) you need to implement unification (which is necessary to match your rules against the facts etc.) 3) depth-first search and resolution. In total, this is not that easily done. It is also possible to use prolog as a back-end to solve the logical part and use php for presentation. Would this be a possible way to go?